# USB 3.0 device with additional AUX power port (both USB-C) - proper schematics?

Tags: usb-device

I'm designing the USB-C 3.0 device which has MAIN power coming from a classic USB 3.0 port of PC/laptop (limited to 900mA in worst case). I'd like to add additional USB-C port for external AUX power supply 1-2A (whether it is charger or another port I guess there's no difference?). It all goes through eFuse to LDOs/Buck-->MCU, etc.

Here's the schematics I came up with. I'm afraid of leakage current of AUX  Schottky, it 's in 1-8mA range typically, that goes to Main USB (and to PC). Is that cool? Any potential issues? (I've prototyped design and it works just fine, but I'd like to improve if possible, without huge redesign).

[image]

Comment: "it works just fine, but I'd like to improve if possible" - improve in what way?

Comment: Mainly I'm not sure, if its OKAY to have a leakage current to the USB port. Is it a common practice - my approach?

Comment: Why have you chosen two different parts to do almost identical jobs?

Comment: Thanks, thats a good point. I was thinking at first to add 5A diode to the AUX but later figured that I don't need so much, so now I have swapped to both identical diodes, with smaller leak.current (but it's still in mAmps

Comment: mA?? At 40V and 125 degrees maybe, but the DFLS240 has a leakage of less than 1uA at 5V and room temperature according to [the datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DFLS240.pdf)

Comment: ha...you're right...I don't know why I was looking at value @100C...totally missed, thanks a lot for pointing me!!!